# Jquery for click content slideshow picture change

Tags: jquery

```
$(".item_1").click(function(){  
  var i =1;
  if (i<=3){
    $("#slideshowWindow").wrapInner('<div class="slides" />');
    $('<img src="Content_Slide1/'+i+'.png" height="100%" width="100%"/>').appendTo($(".slides"));
    i++
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? What I want is my html become below:

```
<div id="slideshowWindow"> 
  <img id="Slide_image1" src="Content_Slide1/1.png" height="100%" width="100%" />
</div>
<div class="slide">
  <img id="Slide_image2" src="Content_Slide1/2.png" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
</div>
<div class="slide">
  <img id="Slide_image3" src="Content_Slide1/3.png" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
</div>
```

if I put the html code same as below, the slide show works!! Then, I deleted ALL the div slide class. Use the Jquery code I use above, tried to change the slide image group by following the click item.

Do you have any idea what I did wrong??

```
<div class="Main" style="background-image:url(images/bg.jpg)">
  <div class="slide"><img></div>
  <div class="slide"><img></div>
  <div class="slide"><img></div>
</div><!--/slideshowWindow-->
```

Comment: clarify your point and language, please!

Comment: Missing syntax, mixing double and single quotes. A `for` loop might be better...

Comment: Every time you click on `.item_1`, it will re-set `i` to 1, so it will always be 1 and thus always add the same image.

Comment: @elcanrs - Maybe you should have posted below? lol, easy karma this was.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".item_1").click(function(){  
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i += 1) {
    $("#slideshowWindow").wrapInner('<div class="slides" />');
    $('<img src="Content_Slide1/' + i + '.png" height="100%" width="100%"/>')
      .append($(".slides"));
  }
});
```

This might be what you're aiming for. (not tested)

**EDIT**

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKVnx/) of what I think you want after your edit.  I used the [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method in jQuery.

**EDIT 2**

I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKVnx/2/) so the html output would match your output html.

```
<div class="Main"> 
  <div class="slide"><img src="//lorempixel.com/400/400/abstract/1/" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="//lorempixel.com/400/400/abstract/2/" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="//lorempixel.com/400/400/abstract/3/" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I just added some text to the html that I'm appending.

**Please read up on the tools you are using: [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page), [js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)**

Comment: I was trying to put this inside a slideshow holder, which is still not working!!!  Only the first picture is show, all the others are not showing.  Any idea??  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: In the jsfiddle you can try replacing the ".slides" selector to where you want to put the images into.  What would be the selector of your slideshow holder? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/